# How to get property in __getattr__ method?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I need to override the `__getattr__` method, but how to I get properties there?

I can access the attributes from the `__getattr__` method like this:

```
class Someclass:
    @property
    def some_prop(self):
        return something

    def __getattr__(self, attr_name):
        return self.__dict__[attr_name]
```

but it won't work if `attr_name == 'some_prop'`, how to access some_prop there?

**EDIT:** this is not the question about how to solve '2+2 = x', this is the question about metaprogramming in python, the provided example is just for illustration of the problem

Comment: properties belong to the class, so you'd have to also check `type(self).__dict__` for the possible property

Comment: But why are you doing this, given that this is the default behaviour already?

Comment: @DanielRoseman because I need to override it to do some complex metaprogramming, the provided example is just for the sake of this question  And this doesn't seem like the default behavior, because there is no 'some_prop' in .__dict__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `self.some_prop()`? 
Because it works.

But also `self.__class__.some_prop.__get__(self, self.__class__)` if you just want to do it differently.

Besides that, you are aware that `__getattr__` won't be called for a reference for `instance.some_prop`, right? Since the descriptor exists, `__getattr__` is not called. (Also, that is why it works).

If you need to intercept the references for `instance.some_prop` itself, you will need to implement `__getattribute__`  instead - that is unconditionally called for **all** your attribute references.

In that case, I'd recommend simply call `super().__getattribute__` unconditionally, and just check afterwards if the attribute was `some_prop`. If not, just return the original value.